# How to run a localhost address while connected with ssh

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, ssh, deployment

Firstly - apologies for the most likely stupid question, I am a total beginner in that fields. I am connected to an AWS server via ssh and I have successfully installed Elasticsearch and transferred an application, which I want to run with npm. On my local machine, when i run `npm start` I get transferred to `http://localhost:3000/` and everything works just fine. How can I see, if the app is working on the AWS server as well? Is there a way to open a browser or something like that? I am interacting solely with the terminal so far.

Thank you!!

Edit: The command `curl http://localhost:3000/` outputs the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Web site created using create-react-app"
    />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/logo192.png" />
    <!--
      manifest.json provides metadata used when your web app is installed on a
      user's mobile device or desktop. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/
    -->
    <link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json" />
    <!--
      Notice the use of  in the tags above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.

      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.

      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.

      To begin the development, run `npm start` or `yarn start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build` or `yarn build`.
    -->
  <script src="/static/js/bundle.js"></script><script src="/static/js/0.chunk.js"></script><script src="/static/js/main.chunk.js"></script></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try `curl http://localhost:3000/` to confirm that you can connect.

Comment: From the output I am getting I should be connected (see edit).

Answer (score 0):

Try `curl http://localhost:3000/` to confirm that you can connect. It's a good quick test to confirm if you have a working service.

Comment: Thank you! I have done that - apparently it seems to work. But what I am interested now is, whether the functionality of the application is as it should be. From reading a couple of related problems, I can use some `DISPLAY` commands is that correct?

Comment: All you should need to do is open port 3000 via the security group, and then connect remotely via your browser.

Answer (score 0):

`npm build` starts a development server on your `localhost` and loads the page. Your scripts section of your `package.json` file will indicate if you have a build script in there (you likely do).

Within your package.json file, there should be an object that looks similar to this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test:cov": "npm test -- --coverage --watchAll=false",
    "test:debug": "react-scripts --inspect-brk test --runInBand",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
}
```

*(your start and build lines may look different but that's fine)*

Your build script will create a production build and will likely put that in a /build or /public directory after the build script is complete.

So try `npm build` on your command line on your local machine instead of `npm start`. You can then put the contents of your /build (or /public) directory onto your AWS server (running as a webserver with ports 80 and 443 accessible to the public) and you can then access the site via the IP address or via the domain name if you've mapped the A record to your server's IP via Route53.